# Could not find driver on insert for a failed job

Tags: laravel-10, job-queue, postgres15

I can't seem to find the reason for the below error log:
`[2024-03-07 16:28:32] local.ERROR: could not find driver (Connection: postgres, SQL: insert into "failed_jobs" ("connection", "queue", "payload", "exception", "failed_at") values (redis, default, {"data":{"command":"O:36:\"Illuminate\\Events\\CallQueuedListener\":19:{s:5:\"class\";s:35:\"App\\Listeners\\UpsertAudienceProfile\";s:6:\"method\";s:6:\"handle\";s:4:\"data\";a:1:{i:0;O:32:\"App\\Events\\AudienceProfileUpdate\":2:{s:4:\"data\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:8:\"John Doe\";s:3:\"age\";s:2:\"19\";}s:8:\"personId\";N;}}s:5:\"tries\";N;s:13:\"maxExceptions\";N;s:7:\"backoff\";N;s:10:\"retryUntil\";N;s:7:\"timeout\";N;s:17:\"shouldBeEncrypted\";b:0;s:3:\"job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:19:\"chainCatchCallbacks\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:11:\"afterCommit\";N;s:10:\"middleware\";a:0:{}s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}","commandName":"Illuminate\\Events\\CallQueuedListener"},"maxTries":null,"failOnTimeout":false,"attempts":1,"type":"event","timeout":null,"tags":{},"id":"20256afe-042f-4053-bc25-2c48ecaedf85","maxExceptions":null,"pushedAt":"1709828820.1984","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","uuid":"20256afe-042f-4053-bc25-2c48ecaedf85","silenced":false,"retryUntil":null,"backoff":null,"telescope_uuid":"9b820df2-09dc-4c67-aa7d-5d9ea22f6c8d","displayName":"App\\Listeners\\UpsertAudienceProfile"}, Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Listeners\UpsertAudienceProfile has been attempted too many times. in /var/www/audience-platform-web-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/MaxAttemptsExceededException.php:24`

I'm using Postgres as DB for the table "failed_jobs".

Laravel version: v10.44.0

PHP version: 8.3

Postgres version: 15

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

I also installed and enabled php extensions pgsql and pdo_pgsql, but this didn't help.

Comment: you need to ensure that the pdo_pgsql extension is installed and enabled

Comment: @KarlHill I already tried this, but thanks for looking into.